# Regex: How to match substrings not starting with a list of prefixes

Tags: regex, list, prefix

I need to replace matching words within a string, but excluding a list of prefixes of those words.

```
The matchingWord should be replaced in the first line
But excludePrefix1.matchingWord , not in this line
Neither in this other line excludePrefix2.matchingWord
But again in this allowedPrefix.matchingWord
```

I succeed with a regex with a single prefix:

```
(?<!(excludePrefix1\.))matchingWord
```

But how can I do that with several excluded prefixes ?

I tried stuff like :

```
(?<!((excludePrefix1\.)(excludePrefix2\.)))matchingWord
```

but that doesn't work, please can a regex expert help us on this tricky matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In several tools negative lookbehind must be fixed length, for your problem use multiple lookbehind:

```
(?<!excludePrefix1\.)(?<!excludePrefix2\.)matchingWord
```